# Can't read any XML files in Rstudio

Tags: r, xml, parsing

I'm trying to load a sample xml into Rstudio, but despite following documentation to the letter and even copy pasting the code, I'm getting an error when it comes to saving the parsed file into a variable

My code is as follows:

```
library("XML")

library("methods")
result <-xmlParse(file="C:\Users\username\Desktop\r_test\input.xml")
print(result)
```

But I always get the error

```
Error in print(result) : object 'result' not found
```

Even though XML is installed and it's being loaded. Any ideas if there's some other error present in the code?

Comment: Code cannot be compilable in R as backslashes must be escaped. You should have received earlier error.

Comment: Adding on to @Parfait's comment, it won't work for use because we don't have your `input.xml` input file. Once you remedy the unescaped backslashes, perhaps you can provide (1) errors from the call to `xmlParse`, and if none, then (2) a sample of your `input.xml` file (a big enough sample that reproduces your problem).

Comment: A very small mistake, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the backslashes ( `\` ) in your file path to forward slashes ( `/` ).  R uses backslashes as an escape character, so they can't be used in strings in quite the normal fashion.  If you'd like to use them they'll need to be doubled ( `\\` ), which in the case of a file path is also equivalent to using a forward slash.

Comment: Not completely true, @Greg. They can be used in strings as normal characters when properly escaped, so the above path *could* be `"C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\r_test\\input.xml"`. Fortunately, R can use the forward-slash as a path delimiter on Windows (in addition to escaped backslashes), so your suggestion to use `"C:/Users/username/Desktop/r_test/input.xml"` works, too.

Comment: Fair point about the double backslashes - I'll edit my answer.